# If I skip a nightly build update, will the next one cover it?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I'm updating every three days, but I only get the latest nightly build, am I lose something?

Comment: yes, intermittent bugs ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each nightly is a full encompassed install. 
CyanogenMod doesn't do cumulative updates for anything.